# Use less MySQLi queries

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to make a system to display information from a user database and it will then display it in a table, however, the issue I have is pageload, and I will be needing three of these and I think I've gone the longest possible route. the page will need to display recipient and type, now in my database I have 5 types of information and it currently counts them each and then displays them as good bad and flagged. can I use less MySQL

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * 
        FROM `user_flags`
        ORDER BY user_flags.timestamp DESC
        LIMIT 15");
    ?>
                                <tbody>
    <?php

    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {

        $GoodRepSql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM user_flags 
            WHERE user_flags.recipient = {$row['recipient']} 
            AND type = 'Good Rep' ");

        if ($GoodRepSql->num_rows > 0) {
            while($goodrow = $GoodRepSql->fetch_assoc()) {
                $GoodRep = $goodrow["COUNT(*)"] ;
            }
        } else {
            $GoodRep = $goodrow["COUNT(*)"] ;
        }

        $BadRepSql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM user_flags 
            WHERE user_flags.recipient = {$row['recipient']} 
            AND type = 'Bad Rep' ");

        if ($BadRepSql->num_rows > 0) {
            while($badrow = $BadRepSql->fetch_assoc()) {
                $BadRep = $badrow["COUNT(*)"] ;
            }
        } else {
            $BadRep = $badrow["COUNT(*)"] ;
        }

        $FlagSql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM user_flags 
            WHERE user_flags.recipient = {$row['recipient']} 
            AND type IN ('Smurfing', 'Griefing', 'Suspicious')");
        if ($FlagSql->num_rows > 0) {
            while($flagrow = $FlagSql->fetch_assoc()) {
                $Flags = $flagrow["COUNT(*)"] ;
            }
        } else {
            $Flags = $flagrow["COUNT(*)"] ;
        }

        echo
            "<tr onclick=\"document.location = '{$url}/{$row['recipient']}';\">
            <td>{$Recipient->players->player->personaname}</td>
            <td>{$BadRep}</td>
            <td>{$GoodRep}</td>
            <td>{$Flags}</td>
            </tr>\n";
    }

?>
```

Comment: add an index on the  `user_flags.recipient ` and the  `user_flags.type ` columns in order to speed up your queries.

Comment: Your indenting style has much to be desired... Mind if I edit your question?

Comment: `if ($GoodRepSql->num_rows > 0) {` *et al* -- This makes no sense for a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query. It will never have 0 rows. Also in your `else`s, `$goodrow`, `$badrow`, and `$flagrow` are undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the count for each type you can use: `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT COUNT(*),type FROM user_flags WHERE user_flags.recipient = {$row['recipient']} GROUP BY type
```

Since you want some of the types to be added together you would need to add them using php.

```
$RepSql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) as repcount,type FROM user_flags WHERE user_flags.recipient = {$row['recipient']} GROUP BY type ");
    $GoodRep=$BadRep=$Flags=0;   
if ($RepSql->num_rows > 0) {
            while($rep_row = $RepSql->fetch_assoc()) {
                if( $rep_row["type"]=='Smurfing'||$rep_row["type"]=='Griefing'||$rep_row["type"]=='Suspicious'){
                    $Flags+=$rep_row["repcount"];
                }else if($rep_row["type"]=="Good Rep"){
                    $GoodRep=$rep_row["repcount"];
                }else if($rep_row["type"]=="Bad Rep"){
                    $BadRep=$rep_row["repcount"];
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You probably want to select `type` as well

Comment: Hey, that's fantastic haha, dumbs down the SQL queries, thanks alot! however I'm having an issue with -   `if ($Sql->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $Sql->fetch_assoc()) {
                if( $row["type"]=='Smurfing'||$row["type"]=='Griefing'||$row["type"]=='Suspicious'){
                    $Flags+=$row["repcount"];
                }else if($row["type"]=="Good Rep"){
                    $GoodRep=$row["repcount"];
                }else if($row["type"]=="Bad Rep"){
                    $BadRep=$row["repcount"];
                }
            }
        }` -  non-object

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Xxampp\htdocs\index.php on line 95 --> I think it's because there's not $row['recipient'] to get the ID from, I think I'll need two queries, one to select * order by most recent (timestamp) then use that to run the query, you also had (GROYP, fixed that to GROUP)

Comment: i changed the second $row variable name Give it another try.If your first query returns normally it should work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111799/discussion-between-george-pant-and-shea-lavington).